# RegExp for splitting a list of emails into basic components (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I almost have this working, but not quite.

I have a JavaScript string that contains a list of emails each formatted differently (no newlines, edited for legibility's sake):

```
var emailList = 'peter@pan.com, 
lucky <jack@pot.com>, 
"William Tell" <billy@tell.com>, 
"John Rambo, III" <johnny@rambo.com>, 
"there, might, be, several, commas inside the quotes" <multiple@commas.com>, 
"yes, this is also a valid email address, can you believe" <yes@this@is@valid.com>'
```

Firstly, I need to split this string into the different emails. Emails are separated by `', '`:

`peter@pan.com, lucky <jack@pot.com>`

but `', '` also might occur in names enclosed by quotes:

`"John Rambo, III" <johnny@rambo.com>`

Even multiple commas can be found inside quotes:

`"there, might, be, several, commas inside the quotes" <multiple@commas.com>`

> Step 1: replace `,` enclosed in quotes

I'd like to substitute the commas for something like `<<<<!!!!>>>>`

I've tried this regexp: `(".*)(,)(\s.*"), $1<<<<!!!!>>>>$3` https://regex101.com/r/baha69/1/ but it's NOT replacing commas within quotes... :-(

> Step 2: split array and undo comma substitution

This can be easily done now in JavaScript with split and replace:

```
var Array = emailList.split(', ');
Array.forEach(function(element, index, arr) {
  arr[index] = element.replace("<<<<!!!!>>>> ", ", ");
});
```

at this point, I should have an array like this (no newlines, edited for legibility's sake):

```
Array[0] = 'peter@pan.com'
Array[1] = 'lucky
            <jack@pot.com>'
Array[2] = '"William Tell"
            <billy@tell.com>'
Array[3] = '"John Rambo, III"
            <johnny@rambo.com>'
Array[4] = '"there, might, be, several, commas inside the quotes
            <multiple@commas.com>'
Array[5] = '"yes, this is also a valid email address, can you believe"
            <yes@this@is@valid.com>'
```

> Step 3: split email addresses

Now I have to turn each individual email into basic components (no newlines, edited for legibility's sake):

```
Array[0] = {fullName: '',
            firstWord: '', localPart: 'peter', company: 'pan', 
            email: 'peter@pan.com'}
Array[1] = {fullName: 'lucky',
            firstWord: 'lucky', localPart: 'jack', company: 'pot', 
            email: 'jack@pot.com'};
Array[2] = {fullName: 'William Tell',
            firstWord: 'William', localPart: 'billy', company: 'tell',
            email: 'billy@tell.com'};
Array[3] = {fullName: 'John Rambo, III',
            firstWord: 'John', localPart: 'johnny', company: 'rambo',
            email: 'johnny@rambo.com'};
Array[4] = {fullName: 'there, might, be, several, commas inside the quotes', 
            firstWord: 'there', localPart: 'multiple', company: 'commas',
            email: 'multiple@commas.com'};
Array[5] = {fullName: 'yes, this is also a valid email address, can you believe', 
            firstWord: 'yes', localPart: 'yes@this@is', company: 'valid',
            email: 'yes@this@is@valid.com'};
```

To do that I'll use the following RegExps:

```
var firstWord = element.match('/"?(\w*),? .*"?/ig')[1];
```

this works!! :-)
https://regex101.com/r/6Z481l/1

```
var fullName = element.match('/"?(.*)"? </ig')[1];
```

this DOESN'T work: captures trailing " :-(
https://regex101.com/r/6Z481l/2

```
var localpart = element.match('/<(.*)@/ig')[1];
```

this DOESN'T work: peter in peter@pan is not captured :-(
https://regex101.com/r/6Z481l/3

```
var company = element.match('/@(.*)\./ig')[1];
```

this works!! :-)
https://regex101.com/r/6Z481l/4

```
var email = element.match('/<(.*@.*)>|(^[^<].*[^>])/ig')[1];
```

surprisingly, this works!! :-) But I'm almost certain it can be made more elegant
https://regex101.com/r/6Z481l/5

> Worth mentioning, emails are presumed to be validated

So, I need some help to complete steps 1 and 3. If any working regexp from step 3 can be simplified or made more elegant, I'll learn from that!

Not the goal, but if you come up with ONE magic RegExp that splits the email like I need it, then I can guarantee you are going to certainly wow me and make me feel very small for my lack of RegExp knowledge!!! :-)

Thanks!

Comment: `var Array = ` I highly recommend not shadowing the built-in Array object

Comment: Are full names always in double quotes if they are not a single word?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Good point!! I never do, the variable in code is called `stringArray`, but it was too long for SO legibility and I shortened it leaving `Array`. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to get your expected end result using regex:

```
(?:(?:"?((\w+)\b.*\b)"?)\s)?<?(([\w@]*)@(\w*)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})>?,?
```

and replacing it with:

```
{ fullName:'\1', firstWord:'\2', localPart:'\4', company:'\5', email:'\3'}
```

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Opwq4S/2)

Comment: Thanks Matt.G! I modified to better parse the email since your solution was dependent on a specific number of @ appearing. Basically I wanted to parse an email address like this:
part1@part2.part3
part1 = ANYTHING before the last @
part2 = ANYTHING between the last @ and the last .
part3 = ANYTHING after the last .

So I modified your utterly brilliant regexp to this: 
`(?:(?:"?((\w+)\b.*\b)"?)\s)?(?:(?:<?((\S+)@((\S+)\.\S+))>?))`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Opwq4S/6

Lesson learnt: matching groups, nested capturing groups and replacing in 1 go. B-R-I-L-L-I-A-N-T-! I feel small...

Comment: I found this very appropriate: https://xkcd.com/208/ Except I'm using JavaScript and not Perl... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string at a comma excluding those enclosed in quotes like [this](https://regex101.com/r/en1Rvd/1/):

```
,(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)
```

This should allow you to get rid of step 1 & 2.

Regarding the non-functional patterns in step 3:

> DOESN'T work: captures trailing "

- [`(?|"(\[^"\]+)"|(.*) <)`](https://regex101.com/r/6Z481l/8): first match balanced quotes, alternatively everything before `<`.
  Caveat: you have to check group 2 if group 1 is empty (unfortunately, JS has no [branch reset](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) group).

> DOESN'T work: peter in peter@pan is not captured

- [`(<|^)(.*)@`](https://regex101.com/r/6Z481l/7): you could secondarily match from the start;
  however, this is troublesome since the pattern is not properly anchored.

For the email validation part you should use one of the [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) and [recommended](http://emailregex.com/) solutions. But that's a another topic, I guess.

Comment: Thanks @wp78de!! This approach worked. I modified a bit to suit my proper needs: https://regex101.com/r/baha69/2/